# DNS opens but localhost doesn't open on XAMPP

Tags: xampp

[Localhost Result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3GYr.png)

[DNS Resul Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idIGz.png)

When I try to open `http://localhost` **Access forbidden!** message appears.
But I redirect `127.0.0.1` to DNS name from `/etc/hosts`. It works.
How can I solve this problem?

---

**My Operation System is:** Mac OS High Sierra.

**Server Version is:** `Apache/2.4.28`

**XAMPP version is:** `7.2.0-0`

Comment: What result do you get if you ping localhost?

Comment: 61 packets transmitted, 61 packets received, 0.0% packet loss

Comment: What does it resolve to?

Comment: it doesn't solved. But terminal gives the result.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it might be a problem with the XAMPP configuration, try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495596/i-get-access-forbidden-error-403-when-setting-up-new-alias

Comment: there is no my solution. My settings are like that...

Comment: Why don't you post your XAMPP configuration?